# Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream. APNS

Tags: notifications, apple-push-notifications, push

I have an app on AppStore, sending notifications to the user, Push notifications were working fine on it till this error occurs on the ASP.net service.
Error:
**Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.**

I have got no idea whats the error about.
I have checked my Provisioning Profile. Its not expired as well.
Kindly Help On This

Comment: Apple disabled SSL3 yesterday. http://www.zdnet.com/apple-leashes-poodle-in-apple-push-notification-pulls-ssl-3-0-7000034996/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple discontinued support for SSL3.0, which is most likely your issue. Change to TLS and restart your service.

Comment: How can I change it? any ideas?

Comment: @dima Look through your service codebase. A find for ssl will probably turn something up. For example, in .NET the `SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient()` method can be switched from ssl to tls by passing a different member of the `System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols` enumeration (`Tls` rather than `Ssl3`) as a parameter